# Identifying/describing sequences of consecutive days with certain value within a vector

Tags: r, subset, sequence

I have a large dataset containing daily values indicating whether that particular day in the year was especially hot or not (indicated by 1 or 0). I aim to identify sequences of 3 or more especially hot days and create a new dataset that contains the length and the start and end date of each.

I'm a bit stuck on how to go about this.

An example of my dataset:

```
hotday <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0)
dates <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("1990-06-01"), by="day",length.out = length(hotday))
df <- data.frame(dates,hotday)
df
        dates hotday
1  1990-06-01      0
2  1990-06-02      1
3  1990-06-03      0
4  1990-06-04      1
5  1990-06-05      1
6  1990-06-06      1
7  1990-06-07      0
8  1990-06-08      0
9  1990-06-09      1
10 1990-06-10      1
11 1990-06-11      1
12 1990-06-12      1
13 1990-06-13      0
```

The output I would like to achieve should look as follows:

```
   startdate    enddate length
1 1990-06-04 1990-06-06      3
2 1990-06-09 1990-06-12      4
```

Thank you for the help, I am willing to take any approach or suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer tidyverse syntax you could do

```r
library(dplyr) 

df %>% 
  mutate(run = cumsum(c(1, abs(diff(hotday))))) %>%
  filter(hotday == 1) %>%
  group_by(run) %>%
  summarize(startdate = first(dates), enddate = last(dates), length = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-run) %>%
  filter(length >= 3)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   startdate  enddate    length
#>   <date>     <date>      <int>
#> 1 1990-06-04 1990-06-06      3
#> 2 1990-06-09 1990-06-12      4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You can even remove `filter(hotday == 1)` since these groups have a length of 0 and thus will be filtered out at the end.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Just a note: I had to detach the library plyr before running this otherwise it gave "'Error in `context_peek()`: ! `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs"

Answer (score 3):

An option is using `rle` in base R or `rleid` from `data.table` - grouped by the run-length-id of the 'hotday' summarise by taking the `first` and `last` of the 'dates' where the number of rows is greater than 2 and 1 is present in hotday

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N >2 && 1 %in% hotday) .(startdate = first(dates),
  enddate = last(dates), length = .N) ,.(grp = rleid(hotday))][,
    grp := NULL][]
```

-output

```
    startdate    enddate length
       <Date>     <Date>  <int>
1: 1990-06-04 1990-06-06      3
2: 1990-06-09 1990-06-12      4
```

Answer (score 1):

The key consideration here is how to assign a unique number of each run of a vector `x`.  Here are some possibilities:

- `collapse::groupid(x)` is a function which does it all for you as in (1)
- a regular expression can be used as in (2)
- `with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))` uses only base R as in (3)
- since we only need it for the runs of 1's -- the numbers assigned to the 0's don't matter since we are going to remove them anyways -- and every 1 in any run of 1's has the same number of 0's preceding it in `x` we can use `cumsum(x == 0)` as in (4)

To some degree these are interchangeable giving rise to additional possibilities by mixing and matching:

**1)** Use `groupid` from collapse to assign a unique number to each run and then for each such run use `filter` to keep it only if it represents a run of `hotday` values and has a run length of at least 3.  Then form the desired summary data and at the end remove the `groupid`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)

df %>%
  group_by(groupid = groupid(hotday)) %>%
  filter(first(hotday) == 1 && n() >= 3) %>%
  summarize(start = first(dates), end = last(dates), length = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-groupid)
## # A tibble: 2 × 3
##   start      end        length
##   <date>     <date>      <int>
## 1 1990-06-04 1990-06-06      3
## 2 1990-06-09 1990-06-12      4
```

**2)** A base R approach that follows the same approach as (1) is shown below.  g corresponds to `groupid` there.

```
stats <- function(x) data.frame(start = x[1], end = tail(x, 1), length = length(x))

df |>
  transform(g = with(rle(hotday), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) |>
  subset(hotday == 1 & ave(g, g, FUN = length) >= 3) |>
  with(by(dates, g, stats)) |>
  do.call(what = "rbind")
##        start        end length
## 4 1990-06-04 1990-06-06      3
## 6 1990-06-09 1990-06-12      4
```

**3)** A completely different approach using only base R is to convert `hotday` to a character string and use `gregexpr` to find the starts and lengths of the 1 runs.

```
g <- gregexpr("1{3,}", paste(df$hotday, collapse = ""))[[1]]
len <- attr(g, "match.length")

with(df, data.frame(start = dates[g], end = dates[g+len-1], lengths = len))
##        start        end lengths
## 1 1990-06-04 1990-06-06       3
## 2 1990-06-09 1990-06-12       4
```

**4)** Another approach is based on the idea that the number of 0's prior to each run of 1's is the same for each element of a particular run of 1's.  This approach uses only base R.

```
df |>
  transform(g = cumsum(hotday == 0)) |>
  subset(hotday == 1) |>
  with(data.frame(start = dates[match(unique(g), g)], 
                  end = dates[findInterval(unique(g), g)],
                  len = c(table(g)))) |>
  subset(len >= 3)
##        start        end len
## 2 1990-06-04 1990-06-06   3
## 4 1990-06-09 1990-06-12   4
```

**4a)** The same idea could be used in (1) to eliminate the need for the groupid function.

```
df %>%
  group_by(groupid = cumsum(hotday == 0)) %>%
  filter(hotday == 1) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  summarize(start = first(dates), end = last(dates), length = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-groupid)
```